# Contribution metric for advisor and code reviewer

Tags: software-development, human-resources, kpi

We are an early-stage software development startup. Recently we have two people who joined our team. John, a co-founder and technical advisor, and Bill, a code reviewer. In short, John's tasks are designing technical specifications and guidance. Bill's task is reviewing code in PR. They won't be available full-time during work hours, so it's more like a flexible part-time. Also, other than stated above, they have no other task, at least for the foreseeable future.
As a PM, I have a task to quantify their contribution toward the product. **This quantitative metrics will translate to John's company share, and Bill's salary**, which can vary from one month to another.
Now it's pretty easy for the task that directly produces something (i.e. design document). However, for the advice and review, it's more challenging to find the quantitative metrics.
I've researched common practices in community and organizations around here, and the two most common are below:

1. Fixed contribution point. 
   Aside from the story point, we'll have a discussion on the contribution point during sprint planning. However, I think one can cheat by marking the point up.
2. Determine from the feature's story point.
   Say if a feature has a story point of 3, make the contribution as 0.5-1 point. It might be the easiest, but I don't think this is the best, because a complex story doesn't necessarily have a complicated review or many advice.

Remember that Bill is paid on monthly basis, so we can't calculate from project outcome.
So what's the most proper way to count the contribution metrics for these two different guys?

Comment: You probably know that quantifying contributions in a team with mostly similar roles is already hard - with different roles it becomes much harder. If you have a mature team and mostly well-defined roles, it should be possible to get some idea of the relative value each one provides per unit of time via self-assessment, peer-assessment, etc. Have regular talks with the team to get a feel of tge correctness of the contribution estimate, but don't open opportunities to game the system, because that might turn people's focus from project success to personal gain.

Comment: The problem is that there is no way to tell if code review is correct or gamed or in between.  My temptation would be reward by Fixed Plus Incentive - with teh incentive being based on decrease in the amount of code rework.  If the code review helps, the code quality should improve and the rework should decline.

Comment: Having a guy that does not actually work in the project and never experienced what went well and what are the pain points do the code review might not actually be a good idea at all. In my experience, ivory tower architects do more harm than good. Hire someone you trust with code reviews to actually work on said code, don't make it a hypothetical based review.